# In a Banach space X, its two Schauder bases have the same cardinal number?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

The definition of Schauder basis is, there exist a set family F(whose cardinal number can be finite countable or uncountable), s.t. any x in X could be uniquely expressed countalbe linear combinations of a subset family S of F.
    I have known that if X is finite Schauder dimension, then two Schauder bases have the same cardinal number. So if X is infinite dimensional, if two bases A and B are meanwhile countable or uncountable, that’s all. However, if A is countable but B is uncountable, how to induce a contradiction?
    It takes me more time to think, hower I can’t solve it. Help me.

Comment: For countable vs. uncountable, ask whether the space is separable or not.  But for (in general) two uncountable cardinals, you will need to do some cardinal arithmetic, like $\aleph_0 \mathfrak m = \mathfrak m$ for all uncountable cardinals $\mathfrak m$.

Comment: Interesting question ... can you have one Schauder base with  cardinal $\aleph_1$ and another with cardinal $\aleph_2$, assuming that $\mathfrak c > \aleph_2$ ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Every *complete minimal system* in a Banach space $X$ has cardinality equal to the *density character* of $X$.

Explanation of terms:

- a family of vectors $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ is *complete* if its linear span is dense in $X$
- it is *minimal* if for every $i$ the closure of the linear span of $(x_j)_{j\ne i}$ does not contain $x_i$
- *density character* $\kappa(X)$ is the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ for which $X$ has a norm-dense subset of cardinality $\kappa$.

Note that every Schauder basis is a complete minimal system. The converse is false; e.g., $\{e^{2\pi inx}:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ is a complete minimal system in $C[0,1]$, but not a Schauder basis.

The proof of the above fact is easy. Since linear combinations with rational coefficients are dense in $X$, the cardinality of a complete minimal system is at least $\kappa(X)$. For the reverse inequality, note that the minimality condition implies that the system is a discrete subset of $X$.

Comment: "For the reverse inequality, note that the minimality condition implies that the system is a discrete subset of X." Why the system is a discrete subset of X? And why this conclusion induces that  the reverse inequality is satisfied? Thank you for replying me.